# How are return values saved?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Does a method/function's call statement hold its return value similar to a how a variable name holds a value?

For example:

```
function Jump(height) {
    return height * 2;
}
Jump(3);       //Is the call statement 'Jump(3)' equal the return value of 6 similar to

var x = 3;  //how the variable 'x' is equal to the value of 3?
```

---

Edit: I gave the wrong impression by naming the variable and function the same name. I was purely using the variable as a comparison in understanding how return values are saved. I'll word/structure my question better next time.

Comment: I think you're looking for `var myJump = Jump(3); // myJump is now 6`

Comment: @corsiKa I think that's the *answer* OP needed

Comment: The return value is'nt stored anywhere unless you actually assign it to a variable, like in the above comment.

Comment: Maybe not a good idea to get the variable and the function the same name ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A little about expressions**

Following your edit, it seems you're asking about `expressions`.

An `expression` is basically a snippet that has a `value`. In your example both `Jump(3)` and `var x = 3` are expressions, as both have a value. In other words, `Jump(3)` is an expression with the value `6` and `(x=3)` is actually an expression which evaluates to `3`.

The only difference between the two is that the first expression also assigns a value with the `assignment operator` (i.e. `=`), while the second expression is "just" a value. For that matter, in your example, the variable `x` is also an expression that evaluates to `3`.

For more on this subject see [MDN - Expressions and operators in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators)

**More to the point**

This means that when you pass an argument to a function [by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value), you're essentially passing the value of the expression. So in your example, `Jump(x)`, `Jump(3)`, `Jump((x=3))` and `Jump(Jump(1.5))` would all evaluate to `6`.

Naturally, it's much less costly to store the value of common operations in a variable that would be quickly evaluated as an expression, than to have the calculation done each time the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 6):

functions and variables share the same namespace.  You defined the function `Jump` and then called it (but didn't actually assign the results of the function (what was returned)), so it returned 6 but then you didn't actually store it anywhere.  Then you overwrote your function by redefining it as a variable with the same name, and just assigned it the value of 3

Comment: If I don't manually store the function's return value inside a variable, how is the return value used as an argument for another function? i.e. run(jump(3));

Is the return value stored "behind the scenes"?

Comment: doing that is okay because you are passing the value to `run()`.  The value will then be stored in the first arg inside run, eg: `function run(arg1) {  alert('arg1); }`  in that example, `arg1` now has the value and its stored there (but only during the execution and scope of the `run` function).

Comment: So calling a function is similar to a math calculation. i.e. 5 * 4 = 20 where 20 is its return value. If we wanted to multiply another number to that product, we wouldn't have to write: 5 * 4 = 20, 20 * 2 = 40 . We could simply write: 5 * 4 * 2 = 40. The expression (5 * 4) implicitly equals 20, so we can use the whole expression in place of the answer. It this a correct comparison functions and return values?

Comment: more or less, yes.  But in general, a function doesn't have to return anything special (if you do not specify a return value, it will return nothing (null). You can just make a function perform some arbitrary action.  In essence, functions are just a convenient way to wrap a label around some code so that you can execute some code over and over in multiple places, instead of typing it all out over and over